# Why imagerendition xml not overwrite after activate custom feature?

Tags: image-rendition

I have created a custom feature which provision a custom imagerendition xml file. It needs to overwrite the current imagerendition xml file. See here the elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ImageRenditions" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="ImageRenditions\PublishingImageRenditions.xml" Url="PublishingImageRenditions.xml" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" ReplaceContent="true">
      <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x01010012BCF119622FF14793A8A38D5831F25C" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Document" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

The feature is site collection scoped and is hidden. The build action of the xml file is "content".

I see the "PublishingImageRenditions.xml" in the gallery and is the original 1.0 version and is checked in and published.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. The feature which was deployed was empty. The feature.xml needs to have a reference to the module.